# Spring-boot with MyBatis doesn't rollback transactions

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I've got a Spring Boot (version 2.1.8.RELEASE) web application (deployed inside a Wildfly 9 application container), with MyBatis, being auto-configured using the Spring Boot starter, but when using the `@transactional` annotation, the statements are always committed, even when they should be rolled back.  My pom.xml fragment looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I've got the following lines in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://my.server.com:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase
spring.datasource.username=myUsername
spring.datasource.password=myPassword
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

And this is my mybatis-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="localCacheScope" value="STATEMENT"/>
    </settings>
    <typeAliases>
        <package name="my.package.model"/>
    </typeAliases>
    <mappers>
    ...
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

My application initialiser class looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("my.packag e")
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) 
    {
        // some config here

        return builder.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
    } // end method configure()

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        // some config here
    } // end method onStartup()

    // some other beans here

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(ServletInitializer.class, args);
    }

} // end class ServletInitializer
```

I've got a controller, which isn't part of the transaction but which autowires in a service layer bean:

```java
@Controller
public class DataMigrationController
{

    @AutoWired private MyService service;

    @GetMapping("/path")
    public @ResponseBody Boolean something(Model model, HttpSession session)
    {
        service.doTask();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And my service class is like this:

```java
@Service
public class MyService
{

    @AutoWired private MyMapper mapper;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Throwable.class) 
    public void doTask()
    {
        Person p= new Person();
        p.setPersonID("999999");
        p.setSurname("TEST");
        p.setForename1("TEST");
        p.setTitle("Mr");

        mapper.insertPerson(p);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

I would expect the transaction to be rolled back because of the `RuntimeException` being thrown at the end of the `doTask()` method but when I check the database, the row is present.  I've also tried using `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();` instead of throwing the exception, but I get the same result.

I'm using the transaction debug class suggested by [this blog post](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2012/04/19/tips-for-debugging-springs-transactional-annotation/) which tells me that there's no transaction in the controller (which I would expect) and there is one in the service class.  But for some reason, the transaction just isn't rolling back.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: It's SQL Server 2017.

Comment: @Raj what is the jdbc driver version you haved used? And have you try Transactional (no need to declare rollback).

Comment: @Ian the version is 7.2.2.jre8 (using Maven to get it, artifactId `mssql-jdbc`), and yes, I've tried without the `rollbackFor` parameter and get the same result.

Comment: Did you have DataSourceTransactionManager bean declared?

Comment: @Ian: no, I haven't declared that - is that something that needs to be done manually, or is it done implicitly for me by Spring Boot?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can help, but I would take a look if you could share a complete (and minimum) project that replicates the issue on GitHub or alike.

Comment: @ave: I've uploaded a cut down project that shows this problem as a zipped Eclipse project to https://github.com/lordofthemoon/mybatisTransactionTest.  Note: this is a web application (war file) that we deploy on a Wildfly 9 server. You'll need to create a SQL Server database and run schema.sql to create the required table. You'll also need to set your database URL and credentials in the honorary.properties file (in src/main/resources).

Comment: I saw you got your answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/issues/383). FYI, cross-posting is not [recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) in general. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reason that commit a transaction. The Spring Boot use JTA transaction management under Java EE(Jakarta EE) environment by default settings. But the `DataSource` that created via Spring Boot can not join it.

You can select a solution as follows:

- Disable the JTA transaction management
- Use a transactional `DataSource` managed by Wildfly

### How to disable JTA transaction management

You can disable the JTA transaction management as follow:

```
spring.jta.enabled=false
```

For details, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jta.

### How to use a `DataSource` managed by Wildfly

You can use the a `DataSource` managed by Wildfly.

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/demo
```

For details, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource

Note: How to configure a `DataSource` (need to enable JTA) on Wildfly, see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/DataSource+configuration?_sscc=t.